# How to return multiple types from a function in C?

Tags: c, function, struct, return-value

I have a function in C which calculates the mean of an array. Within the same loop, I am creating an array of t values. My current function returns the mean value. How can I modify this to return the t array also?

```
/* function returning the mean of an array */
double getMean(int arr[], int size) {
   int i;
   printf("\n");
   float mean;
   double sum = 0;
   float t[size];/* this is static allocation */
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sum += arr[i];
        t[i] = 10.5*(i) / (128.0 - 1.0);
        //printf("%f\n",t[i]);
   }
   mean = sum/size;
   return mean;
}
```

**Thoughts:**
Do I need to define a struct within the function? Does this work for type scalar and type array? Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Comment: `float t[size];/* this is static allocation */` <- just no. This has normal *automatic* storage duration.

Comment: Your title says *multiple types*, but the question reads more like you want to return *multiple values*. Please clarify.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by automatic storage duration?

Comment: I want to return a single value for the mean, and an array, t.

Comment: Well, I mean what the C standard means. *Automatic storage duration* means the variable lives for exactly the time the execution is in its scope.

Comment: Create a struct to contain two fields, an array and a double. It is also important for you to understand that anything declared inside the function won't be there after it's finish. You need to allocate it prior to your function and send to the function (the struct).

Comment: Unrelated, but don't use `float` without a very good reason, as it has **very** limited precision. Always use `double`.

Comment: @TonyTannous or return an *allocated object* that the caller has to `free()` when done with it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen also true.

Comment: Great advice, thanks. I only started learning C this week so I have a lot to learn.

Comment: @Sjoseph don't let the downvotes deter you from asking questions :) it's just a way to indicate the question was poorly formatted, read the "how to ask section" for future questions. The answer down below is very simple yet elegant.

Comment: Thanks, Tony. I will structure it better the next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the advice suggested by [@FelixPalmen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45487669/6879826) is probably the best choice. But, if there is a maximum array size that can be expected, it is also possible to wrap arrays in a `struct`, without needing dynamic allocation. This allows code to create new `struct`s without the need for deallocation.

A `mean_array` structure can be created in the `get_mean()` function, assigned the correct values, and returned to the calling function. The calling function only needs to provide a `mean_array` structure to receive the returned value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAX_ARR  100

struct mean_array {
    double mean;
    double array[MAX_ARR];
    size_t num_elems;
};

struct mean_array get_mean(int arr[], size_t arr_sz);

int main(void)
{
    int my_arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    struct mean_array result = get_mean(my_arr, sizeof my_arr / sizeof *my_arr);

    printf("mean: %f\n", result.mean);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < result.num_elems; i++) {
        printf("%8.5f", result.array[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}

struct mean_array get_mean(int arr[], size_t arr_sz)
{
    assert(arr_sz <= MAX_ARR);
    struct mean_array res = { .num_elems = arr_sz };
    double sum = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < arr_sz; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        res.array[i] = 10.5 * i / (128.0 - 1.0);
    }
    res.mean = sum / arr_sz;

    return res;
}
```

Program output:

```
mean: 3.000000
0.00000 0.08268 0.16535 0.24803 0.33071
```

In answer to a couple of questions asked by OP in the comments:

`size_t` is the correct type to use for array indices, since it is guaranteed to be able to hold any array index. You can often get away with `int` instead; be careful with this, though, since accessing, or even forming a pointer to, the location one before the first element of an array leads to undefined behavior. In general, array indices should be non-negative. Further, `size_t` may be a wider type than `int` in some implementations; `size_t` is guaranteed to hold any array index, but there is no such guarantee for `int`.

Concerning the `for` loop syntax used here, e.g., `for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {}`: here `i` is declared with *loop scope*. That is, the lifetime of `i` ends when the loop body is exited. This has been possible since C99. It is good practice to limit variable scopes when possible. I default to this so that I must actively *choose* to make loop variables available outside of loop bodies.

If the loop-scoped variables or `size_t` types are causing compilation errors, I suspect that you may be compiling in C89 mode. Both of these features were introduced in C99.If you are using gcc, older versions (for example, gcc 4.x, I believe) default to C89. You can compile with `gcc -std=c99` or `gcc -std=c11` to use a more recent language standard. I would recommend at least enabling warnings with: `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra` to catch many problems at compilation time. If you are working in Windows, you may also have similar difficulties. As I understand it, MSVC is C89 compliant, but has limited support for later C language standards.

Comment: Things are starting to make sense! What does the size_t before i  do in the for loops? I noticed that you and Felix used this. I have had to remove this to get the code to execute without error

Comment: @Sjoseph I explained `size_t` in my answer. Include `stddef.h` or `stdlib.h` to use it.

Comment: @Sjoseph just in case this wasn't **entirely** clear in my answer: `size_t` is an unsigned integer type suitable for any possible object size of your target platform. The `sizeof` operator returns a `size_t`. As this heavily depends on other properties of your implementation, `size_t` is specified as a `typedef`, so you have to include the appropriate standard header (see comment above) to use it. `int` isn't a good choice for a size. Not only is it *signed*, but it can be too small as well.

Comment: @FelixPalmen-- `size_t` is also declared in [`stdio.h`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.1p2), so including that header file will suffice.

Comment: @Sjoseph-- `size_t` is the correct type to use for array indices, since it is guaranteed to be able to hold any array index. You can often get away with `int` instead, and sometimes an `int` may seem like the right choice. Note that in the loops, e.g., `for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {}`, here `i` is declared with _loop scope_. That is, the lifetime of `i` ends when the loop body is exited. This has been possible since C99. It is good practice to limit variable scopes when possible. I default to this so that I must actively _choose_ to make loop variables available outside of loop bodies.

Comment: @Sjoseph-- if the loop-scoped variables are causing compilation errors, I suspect that you may be compiling in C89 mode. If you are using gcc, older versions (for example, gcc 4.x, I believe) default to C89. You can compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` to use a more recent language standard. If you are working in Windows, you may also have similar difficulties. Felix is more hip to the ins and outs of working in C  on Windows systems than I am.

Answer (score 4):

You can return only 1 object in a C function. So, if you can't choose, you'll have to make a structure to return your 2 values, something like :

```
typedef struct X{
     double mean;
     double *newArray;
} X;
```

BUT, in your case, you'll also need to dynamically allocate the `t` by using `malloc` otherwise, the returned array will be lost in stack.

Another way, would be to let the caller allocate the new array, and pass it to you as a pointer, this way, you will still return only the mean, and fill the given array with your computed values.

Answer (score 3):

The most common approach for something like this is letting the caller provide storage for the values you want to return. You could just make `t` another parameter to your function for that:

```
double getMean(double *t, const int *arr, size_t size) {
   double sum = 0;
   for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        sum += arr[i];
        t[i] = 10.5*(i) / (128.0 - 1.0);
   }
   return sum/size;
}
```

This snippet also improves on some other aspects:

- Don't use `float`, especially not when you intend to return a `double`. `float` has very poor precision
- Use `size_t` for object sizes. While `int` often works, `size_t` is guaranteed to hold any possible object size and is the safe choice
- Don't mix output in functions calculating something (just a stylistic advice)
- Declare variables close to where they are used first (another stylistic advice)
- This is somewhat opinionated, but I changed your signature to make it explicit the function is passed pointers to arrays, not arrays. It's impossible to pass an array in C, therefore a parameter with an array type is automatically adjusted to the corresponding pointer type anyways.
- As you don't intend to modify what `arr` points to, make it explicit by adding a `const`. This helps for example the compiler to catch errors if you accidentally attempt to modify this array.

You would call this code e.g. like this:

```
int numbers[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
double foo[5];

double mean = getMean(foo, numbers, 5);
```

instead of the *magic number* `5`, you could write e.g. `sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers`.

---

Another approach is to dynamically allocate the array with `malloc()` inside your function, but this requires the caller to `free()` it later. Which approach is more suitable depends on the rest of your program.

Comment: Just to add so it doesn't confuse OP, anything sent by reference to a function, and gets modified inside it,then  the changes are visible from the outside. So you could possibly just send your storage to the function without the need for a struct. Don't forget to allocate the array in the function.

Comment: @TonyTannous The caller is supposed to provide the output array.

Comment: Yes I just like to do it inside if size changes... but a simple solution as well. +1.

Comment: @TonyTannous I'd say letting the caller provide the memory is the *idiomatic C* way of doing this. The advantage is that any object works, automatic, static, allocated ... But of course sometimes you would prefer to allocate the array inside the function and let the caller `free()` it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, When I call this function from the main function, what do I pass to the function for double *t? I have probably missed the point but will this method update the t array inside of the main function or will it only be accessible within the scope of the function getMean?

Comment: @Sjoseph please re-read the whole answer, I think I answered all the questions from your comment there? Saying it explicitly, if you pass an array, a **pointer** is passed instead and of course you can modify the array through that pointer.

Comment: @FelixPalmen. OK, i understand what you mean now. Unfortunately my implementation must be lacking as when I attempt to access t from the main function, the returned value is the mean.

Comment: @Sjoseph what do you mean with *access t*? `t` only exists in your function, but it is a pointer to some array you provide from outside (as in my example, I pass a pointer to `foo`).

Comment: @FelixPalmen. I declared an array t in the main function, which I then passed to the getMean function. After the function call, my understanding was that t would update to the values from the forloop within the getMean function

Comment: @Sjoseph exactly, the function (as shown in my answer here) accesses and modifies it through the pointer.